# JPA Generation in Eclipse

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I am working on the JPA.

I working on it from past 6 months and never faced this problem.

The problem is JPA classes are not getting generated. I mean I use the api of EclipseLink to generate them for any Schema but don't know it was not getting generated.

Although the same schema's JPA is getting generated in Netbeans IDE perfectly. So my concern is, is there any Program that generate the JPA for me. Although I know that I can copy the classes from Netbeans to Eclipse but that is not my solution.

Please help me.....
:(

Comment: What do you mean by "JPA classes"? Do you mean that your Entities are not generated as tables in database?

Comment: @Bevor I think it is the other way round. Ankur wants to have JPA annotated Java classes from an already existing database schema.

Comment: @ppeterka Ok, I see. Didn't know that this is possible.

Comment: Are you talking about metamodel generation or entity generation? what 'api of EclipseLink' are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Without exception traces, logs or other hints, it is a bit difficult to guess the problem, but I had a very similar issue in Eclipse 3.7 and Dali plugins... Do you by any chance have a directory in your path with the name beginning with a `!` ? In my case, that was the problem, I had my path like this:

`D:\!dev\....\eclipse`

and it would not generate the classes. I debugged it, and discovered the problem: after moving my Eclipse into the folder structure

`D:\dev\....\eclipse`

the files were successfully generated. I also filed a [bugzilla report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388631) about this issue.

Comment: My concern is what are the possible reasons for this unusual behaviour

Comment: In my case, this is related to how Eclipse references resources inside a JAR file. These resources (mostly JET templates) are required for generating classes. It uses the ! as a separator character, and thus when a directory name begins with a !, the logic treats this as if the rest of the path was inside a JAR file - when it is not.

For me, also things like generating an RCP application would not work with the folder starting with a ! in the path.